# Why does XCode (4.5.1, Lion) require an internet connection to connect to iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an ios app that doesn't need an internet connection. I'm using phonegap and jquery-mobile. I'd like to develop offline, but XCode gets stuck with a status saying 'Attaching to iosproj' (iosproj is my project name). After that I cannot stop the stuck task, and have to force-quit XCode. With an internet connection however, everything works just fine. Grateful for any clues.

Edit: XCode seems to install the app fine without a network, but it gets stuck before/durimg receiving the deviceready event.

Update 1: The app runs fine on the simulator with or without the n/w. It is purely the XCode-iOS simulator interaction.

Update 2: When using phonegap (Apache cordova), there's an easy work-around to work offline. Once the project has been built and installed (with a n/w), all subsequent updates to html/js/css/img can be made directly to the www directory in the simulator's Library (under your app folder, in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications).

Answer (score 1):

The Simulator itself attempts to make an Internet connection to Apple as it launches. In particular, the `itunesstored` process attempts to connect to ax.init.itunes.apple.com and phobos.apple.com.

[That information comes from LittleSnitch. You would be well advised to install LittleSnitch so that you can be sure of exactly what connection is being attempted here. No one - certainly no developer - should be without it.]

If you find this troublesome (that is, if the connection failure is causing you to be unable to run your app in the Simulator at all) you should file a bug report with Apple. However, I've had no difficulty with this, so perhaps this an Xcode bug. I'd suggest first updating to Xcode 4.5.2 in case it is fixed there.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that earlier, so I ran the iphone simulator on its own (without XCode) and without wifi; the app works just fine.  This is the reason I felt that it has something to do with the XCode-ios simulator interaction. Also, the firewall was disabled.

Comment: I repeat: Don't guess. Use LittleSnitch to see outgoing connections. That way you'll *know* whether the problem is an attempted Internet connection, and exactly what process is trying to make it.

Comment: I used LittleSnitch, and got the same result as you: itunesstored contacts itunes. The ios simulator continues to work fine (along with my earlier installed version of the app) with and without the network, XCode blocks indefinitely without a network while installing/attaching the app.